# Tracing async control flow with com.twitter.util.Future

Tags: scala

[Changelog](https://github.com/twitter/util/blob/master/ChangeLog) for Twitter's util library version 1.12.5 says

> - Futures: trace dispatch "stack", supplying it as a stack trace for
>     exceptions, implement "transform", "transformedBy" to allow for a
>     more imperative control flow when used from Java.

The relevant change seems to be introduction of `Future.Tracer` and `Future.tracer`. However, I get the same exception traces whether `util-reflect.jar` is in the classpath (and `Future.tracer` is an `AsmFutureTracer`) or not. Do I need to do something else to get the improved traces?